# error when converting 2003 visual studio project to 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

[image]

I have an asp.net project which is created in `2003 visual studio` and now i am trying to run it in `2010 visual studio`. and i convert by following the instructions given in `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff956194.aspx` this site, but the problem is when i try to run the project it will show an error in the picture . please somebody help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the answer , there are some `Dll` are missing in my `web application`.When i convert my `website` to `web application` i want to refer some `dlls`. i add that `dll` references to my `webapplication` their after it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you cannot run a class library type project. Check properties of your project and see what type of application it is.

Comment: thanks for your replay sir. i check it in properties and the output type is =class library there and i changed it to web application .now my error changes but it shows some other erros

Comment: now it shows some error : does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point in

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, do these steps:

Right click the Project name in Solution Explorer of Visual Studio Select Set as StartUp Project from the popup menu Re-run your project, it should work!

If it did not work, be sure that you have set your start page. If your project is C# Windows Application or C# Console Application, try this:

Right click the Project name in Solution Explorer of Visual Studio Select Properties Select Application tab In Output type drop box, select the correct application type of your project Re-run your project.

Change the Output Type under the Project > Properties to that of a “Class Library”. By default, this setting may have been set to a “Console Application”

Comment: thanks for your replay , i tried that but now i got a different error  : does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point in c#

Comment: Have you Use Capital M for Main

Comment: Just like static void Main()